# How to integrate necessary native DOM methods like addEventListener with react?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, dom-events

I'm currently working on a project that involves integrating React events with my codebase. However, I'm having trouble incorporating them with certain libraries that do not inherently support `React`, such as `maplibregl`. As a result, I'm compelled to add elements as native HTML, like in the case of adding a custom HTML icon to the marker.

Here's how I do that with `maplibregl`:

`maplibregl`

```
function renderS1Template(r, siteName){
        var template = `
        <div id="${r}" class='map-icon-holder' >
            <img  class='map-icon' src=${S1Icon} />
            <div class='map-icon-label' >
                <label >${siteName}</label>
            </div>
            
        </div>`
        
        return $(template)[0]
    }

        let template = renderS1Template(r, siteName)

            // create the marker with custom html component
            const marker1 = new maplibregl.Marker( template , {
                draggable: true,
                'nodeName' : nodeName
            })
            // .setLngLat([ coordinates.lng, coordinates.lat])
            .setLngLat([data.x, data.y])
            .setPopup(new maplibregl.Popup({ offset: 25 }))
            .addTo(props.callback.mapObject)
```

After doing this, I find myself having to rely on native events, such as `.on('contextmenu')`, to handle interactions. My question revolves around how I can eliminate the need for these native event listeners and fully transition to React events in this context.

My query is, is there a technique or method available that allows for the use of native React events even when dealing with native DOM elements?

Comment: Generally when trying to include a library with an imperative API you wrap it in a React component so it can plug into React properly. Good examples would be the React bindings for [the Google Maps API](https://github.com/JustFly1984/react-google-maps-api) or [three.js](https://github.com/pmndrs/react-three-fiber). Note (and I'm not trying to be offensive) doing so is not usually trivial and requires a fairly deep understanding of how to abstract the imperative bits behind a React component interface. Not really a beginner task.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way, instead of using useState, i think we can use useRef() since it is mutable.